# HOW CAN I RUM TOMCAT as http:\\www.example.com, as it runs on http:\\www.example.com:8080

Tags: web-applications, tomcat7, java

HOW CAN I RUM TOMCAT SITE as http:\www.example.com, as it runs on http:\www.example.com:8080

I have some files in PHP also

Some one guide me how i achieve this task.

Run JAVA Site on http:\www.example.com and also php pages

Thanks in ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

You would need to run tomcat at port 80. Check out this link

[install and run Tomcat on port 80 as my only web server](https://serverfault.com/questions/127110/how-do-i-install-and-run-tomcat-on-port-80-as-my-only-web-server-rooted-ubuntu)

Comment: ya but i also run php with it.

Comment: I don't have much idea about running php on tomcat, may you would need JavaBridge for that:

http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/doc/tomcat6.php